# What is this 'hammer'?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I keep on hearing people referring to the '**hammer**' in the chat rooms, and just generally everywhere (not necessarily on this or other SE sites, even in every day life), so what is this '**hammer**'? I hear phrases being thrown around like the `mod-hammer` and `give them the hammer`, but what is this '**hammer**'? I don't understand... Is there a general meaning for it? Or are there some common meanings for it? I really have no idea what this so called '**hammer**' is about...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [Banhammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banhammer), the show of ultimate force from an admin or sysop to a regular user. It is a metaphor for the ability of individuals with higher privileges on the system to silence ("mute") or remove ("kick" and/or "ban") other individuals.

Comment: I think you've nailed it.

Comment: I saw what you did there.

Comment: To add to this, on some sites the moderators have next to their IDs an icon representing a judges gavel, suggesting that they have decision-making authority.

Comment: +1 for Ignacio. However, let us not forget **The Hammer and Hammer pants** in our haste:https://www.google.com/search?q=Hammer+pants&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMIl4juodzoxwIVTgqSCh0XDAVc&biw=863&bih=451 "The hammer" probably still gets used in that context occasionally.